# Where to find Entlib xsd file?

Tags: configuration, xsd, enterprise-library

Does this file exists? I'm tired of the 'Could not find schema information for attribute' messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no EntLib XSD file. Producing one is tricky as config is dynamic. See discussion here.

http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=10712

Comment: Thanks for the late response and for the link!

Answer (score 2):

One does exist for Entlib 5.0 - it gets installed as part of Entlib 5. Since the Entlib elements don't have XML namespaces, you'll need to explicitly turn it on in VS though (right click on the config file, select "Properties", click on the "Schemas" field, and you'll be able to turn on the schema validation.)

It won't work on everything - Entlib has a highly customizable configuration schema and not everything is representable in XSD, but it's about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: For current VS installs (namely, Visual Studio Professional 2017), you can get a file this way: 1) Download the EL 5.x MSI file; 2) Open the MSI file in a file archiver utility (e.g., 7-Zip); 3) Extract file \ConfigSchema; 4) Optional: Rename ConfigSchema to something descriptive (e.g., EnterpriseLibrary5.xsd); and 5) Add the XSD, in Visual Studio: open web.config, select a tag, XML > Schemas ..., then "Add" and select the file location.  This removed the Intellisense issues for me. Note: deselect any other EL XSD files, if you get duplicate declaration errors.

Comment: Link to Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 MSI: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15104